# Problemas ao inserir dados em uma tabela

Tags: python, sqlite3

Tenho um script em Python que realiza a leitura de mensagens que vem da porta serial.
Ao ler as mensagens, gravo-as em uma lista e envio para grava-las em um banco SQLITE3.
Porém, ao executar, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 1 supplied`
```

```
  import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect(database='dados.db')``

conn = sqlite3.connect(database='dados.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
                  CREATE TABLE dados (
                  titutlo TEXT NOT NULL,
                  command INTEGER NOT NULL,
                  tipo_dispositivo INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                  id_dispositivo TEXT NOT NULL,
                  distancia INTEGER,
                  contador     VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
                  data  INTEGER NOT NULL
                  );
                  """)

while True: 
        command = [ser.readline().decode('utf-8').split('|')] # O decode() aqui é para converter de bytes para string         
        if  command!= '': 
         #   print(command)

            cursor.executemany("""
            INSERT INTO dados(tipo_dispositivo, id_dispositivo, distancia,contador,data)
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""", command)
            conn.commit()





            #print(lista)

conn.close()`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, o seu comando de `INSERT` na tabela `dados` vai falhar pois viola os campos `titulo` e `command` que possuem `CONSTRAINTS` de `NOT NULL`, ou seja, esses campos não podem conter valores nulos e precisam ser especificados na inserção do registro.

O erro que você apontou acontece pois a variável `command` não possui 5 elementos para satisfazer os campos do seu `INSERT`, a variável `command` é, na verdade, uma lista que contém uma outra lista como único elemento:

```
command = [ser.readline().decode('utf-8').split('|')]
```

O correto seria:

```
command = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').split('|')
```

A comunicação de dados através da porta serial está sujeita a interferência de diversos fatores que podem afetar a integridade dos dados recebidos e transmitidos. Quase sempre existe a necessidade da criação de protocolos e [verificação cíclica de redundância](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC) para garantir a integridade dos dados trafegados.

Seu loop principal precisa identificar e tolerar falhas sem parar de receber os dados que estão chegando na porta, ou seja, mesmo que uma linha corrompida seja recebida, o programa saberá identificá-la como um registro malformado e descartá-lo.

Assumindo que os dados lidos da porta serial sejam algo como:

```
foo|X|10|20|30|40|50
bar|Y|11|22|33|44|55
baz|Z|15|25|35|45|55
```

Segue um programa capaz de tolerar as falhas de transmissão e gravação dos dados sem sair do loop principal:

```
import sqlite3
import serial

conn = sqlite3.connect(database='dados.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE dados
    (
        titulo TEXT NOT NULL,
        command INTEGER NOT NULL,
        tipo_dispositivo INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        id_dispositivo TEXT NOT NULL,
        distancia INTEGER,
        contador VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
        data INTEGER NOT NULL
    );""")

# Abre porta serial
ser = serial.Serial( ... )

while True:
    print("Aguardando linha...")

    # Lê uma linha a partir da porta serial
    linha = ser.readline()

    print("Linha recebida.")

    # Codifica dados lidos para uma string UTF-8
    linha = linha.decode('utf-8','ignore').strip()

    # Recupera os campos da linha recebida
    values = linha.split('|')

    # Valida o registro recebido (7 campos)
    if len(values) != 7:
        print("Registro Malformado: Quantidade invalida de campos")
        continue

    print("Gravando registro...")

    try:
        # Insere registro na tabela
        cur.execute("""
            INSERT INTO dados (titulo, command, tipo_dispositivo, id_dispositivo, distancia, contador, data)
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", values)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("O registro nao pode ser gravado: {}".format(e))
        continue

    print("Registro gravado com sucesso")

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Ainda assim não consegui resolver. Eu estou preechendo a tabela através dos dados que o script recebe na porta serial e não a partir de um arquivo .txt
O comando ser.readline() lê a porta serial(que é um sensor  do arduino mandando algumas mensagens). Uso o .split() para ignorar '|' que separam os dados e quero salvar tudo em uma lista, para só entao envia-la ao banco, sendo cada nova linha, uma nova leitura do sensor, entende?

Comment: @GuilhermeDinamarco Ops! Segue edição!